# TFS and storing binary files

Tags: tfs, binary

Our project group stored binary files of the project that we are working on in SVN repository for over a year, in the end our repository grew out of control, taking backups of SVN repo became impossible at one point since each binary that is checked in is around 20 MB.

Now we switched to TFS,we are not responsible for backing the repository up, our IT tream takes care of it and we have more network and storage capacity for backups because of that but we want to decide what to do with the binaries. As far as I know TFS stores deltas and for binary files but deltas will be huge, but we might end up reaching our disk space quota one day, so I would like to plan things better from the start, I don't want to get caught up in a bad situation when it's too late to fix the problem.

I would prefer not keeping builds in the source control but our project group insists to keep a copy of every binary for reproducing the problems that we see in the production system, I can't get them to get the source code from TFS, build it and create the binary, because it is not straightforward according to them.

Does TFS offer a better build versioning method? If someone can share some insight I'd really be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule you should not be storing build output in TFS. Occasionally you may want to store binaries for common libraries used by many applications but tools such as nuget get around that.

Build output has a few phases of its life and each phase should be stored in a separate place. e.g.

**Build output:** When code is built (by TFS / Jenkins / Hudson etc.) the output is stored in a drop location. This storage should be considered volatile as you'll be producing a lot of builds, many of which will be discarded.

**Builds that have been passed to testers:** These are builds that have passed some very basic QA e.g. it compiles, static code analysis tools are happy, unit tests pass. Once a build has been deemed good enough to be given to test it should be moved from the drop location to another area. This could be a network share (non production as the build can be reproduced) there may be a number of builds that get promoted during the lifetime of a project and you will want to keep track of what versions the testers are using in each environment.

**Builds that have passed test and are in production:** Your test team deem the build to be of a high enough quality to ship. As part of your go live process, you should take the build that has been signed off by test and store it in a 3rd location. In [ITIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL) speak this is a [Definitive Media Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitive_Media_Library). This can be a simple file share, but it should be considered to be "production" and have the same backup and resilience criteria as any other production system.

The DML is the place where you store the binaries that are in production (and associated configuration items such as install instructions, symbol files etc.) The tool producing the build should also have labelled the source in TFS so that you can work out what code was used to produce the binary. Your branching strategy will also help with being able to connect the binary to the code.

It's also a good idea to have a "live like" environment, this should be separate from your regular dev and test environments. As the name suggests it contains only the code that has been released to production. This enables you to quickly reproduce bugs in production

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I also think that only important builds that go to production or test environment have to be backed up, and it should never be backed up in TFS. I've been trying to convince them, hope I can find a way:)

Comment: File Shares are the better way to handle this, as mentioned. The problem I've found with storing binaries in TFS is that sometimes the algorithm for detecting a change and if something actually needs to be checked in doesn't detect binary files are changed. This means that any time you need to check in an updated version of a binary you must use FORCE to ensure it actually gets checked in.

Comment: I wish people would just answer the actual question — if only for those who come via Google. I for example want to store binary sources (like PNGs) and now I still don't know how to “storing binary files” .

Comment: @Martin the question was about binary output from a build process. Not binaries in general. So as a rule of thumb think of it like this. If it's source then it goes in version control, if it's the output of a build process then it should not be stored in version control. So in your example (png) then these should be stored in your version control system. There are edge cases where the binaries are large (Many MB / GB in size) such as audio and video. In that case you should be looking at something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management)

Answer (score 1):

Two methods that may help you:

1. Use Team Foundation Build System. One of the advantages is that you can set up retention periods for finished builds. For example, you can order TFS to store the 10 latest successful builds, and the two latest failed ones. You can also tell TFS to store certain builds (e.g. "production builds"/final releases) indefinitely. These binaries folders can of course also be backed up externally, if needed.
2. Use a different collection for your binaries, with another (less frequent) backup schedule. TFS needs to backup whole collections, but by separating data that doesn't change as frequently as the source you can lower the backup cost. This of course depends on the frequency you are required to have the binaries backed up.

Comment: About 1st option, our IDE of choice is eclipse on Debian we use C++ and we heavily use Boost and QT, whereas our companies TFS server is a windows server, is there any way we can use Team Foundation Build System, or do we have to create the same environment under the TFS Server to make the build system work. If so that might be a challange for us, since there is only one TFS server in our enterprise, and lots of bureaucracy.

Comment: second option seems more possible given that I convince my coworkers about doing the right thing

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into creating build definitions in TFS to give your project group an easy 'one button' push to grab the source code from a particular branch and then build it and drop it to a location.  That way they get to have their binaries, and you don't have to source control them.

If you are using a branching strategy where you create Release or RTM branches when you push something to production, then you can point your build definitions at those branches and they can manually trigger them from the TFS portal or from within Visual Studio.

Comment: I need to look into creating build definitions from eclipse and linux, that might be a good option as well.